# Trello API: How do I move a card to a different list

Tags: trello

I have code to read boards, lists, and cards. I'd like to move cards from one list to another. I just can't seem to figure out Trello's API docs. Can someone provide a sample move card string? I see moveCardToBoard but what list would it end up in? Thanks, Tim

Comment: I guess I'm looking for syntax help. Is this close:  https://trello.com/1/cards/<card id>/idList?key=<key>&token=<token>&value=<list id>

Answer (score 20):

You have to use this url:

[PUT /1/cards/[card id or shortlink]/idList](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#put-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-idlist)

Make sure you make a `put` request and you have a proper `token` with write `permission`.

Answer (score 11):

The API appears to have changed.

Now you would use:
[PUT /1/cards/{cardID}?idList={listID}](https://developers.trello.com/reference/#cardsid-1)

Answer (score 0):

If the list is in an other board you can simply do:

`PUT /1/cards/{cardID}?idBoard={boardId}&idList={listID}`

thank's to @Tyler 's answer